# Squeezable, boneless alien pets. Possibly furry. Children's sci fi, circa the '80s?

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, childrens-novel

Does anyone remember a children's sci fi book that features boneless alien pets that are highly squeezable? My extremely fuzzy recollection is that these aliens are furry and friendly, perhaps like dogs.

The book is possibly from the '80s. It is geared towards early elementary school kids, along the lines of My Teacher Is An Alien.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the flat cats of The Rolling Stones, by Robert Heinlein.
The plot concerns a family migrating from Luna to Mars, and the 
cats are a moneymaking scheme, import goods to sell at the destination.

This is one of Heinlein's works for a juvenile audience, but is
well worth reading, if only for the grandma character.

Comment: The Stones aren't migrating to Mars.  The twin sons of the family bought and refurbished an old ship.  The rest of the family decided to travel with them.  Mars is one stop of a trip that it is implied will never end.  The flat cats are mostly discussed on the flight from Mars to the asteroid belt.  The youngest brother got one flat cat on Mars, and it reproduced on the trip.  Flat cats were one of the family's most popular commodities in the asteroid belt.  Can you tell that I re-read that book way too many times as a kid?

Comment: [The Rolling Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rolling_Stones_(novel)) was written in 1952.